# accordion need to be implemented to expand only the child divs on click and stay collapsed by default

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, bootstrap-4

I am using Accordion to achieve collapsible functionality in my navigation pane. I have a large code which is too clumsy when the page loads. Surely, I did not set the accordion tags properly. The parent and child div tags are ordered properly but the collapse functionality doesn't work as intended. First load, I need only the main headings to display and on click only the child tags should come up. Now, everything displays with some sub nodes collapsed. Please look at my code and help me modify it so that I can achieve my functionality properly. Below is my code:

```
<div class="col-md-8 accordion" id="mastercarrier">
                            <div class="">
                                <div class="">
                                    <h4 class="mb-0">
                                        <a class="LinkedObjects" id='' data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#ShowCarriers" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseOne">
                                            Registered Carriers
                                        </a>
                                    </h4>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-12" id="carrierResults" data-parent="#mastercarrier">
                                    <div class="col-md-12">
                                        @{
                                            var count = 0;
                                            var carrierservicecount = 1;
                                            var carrierDocumentcount = 2;
                                            var carrierDocumentOptionscount = 3;

                                            foreach (var carrier in Model.RegisteredCarriers)
                                            {
                                                var idForCarrier = @carrier.Symbol + @count;
                                                var idforcarrierservice = @carrier.Symbol + @carrierservicecount;
                                                var idforcsmain = idforcarrierservice + @count;

                                                var idforcarrierdocument = @carrier.Symbol + @carrierDocumentcount;
                                                var idforcdmain = idforcarrierdocument + @count;

                                                var idforcarrierdocumentoption = @carrier.Symbol + @carrierDocumentOptionscount;
                                                var idforcdoption = @carrierDocumentOptionscount + @count;

                                                <div id="ShowCarriers" class="">
                                                    <div class="parent-Cards" id="carrierParent">
                                                        <div class="parent-Card" id="@carrier.GuID">
                                                            <a class="LinkedObjects" asp-controller="RegisteredCarriersAndDocuments" asp-action="GetCarrier" asp-route-GUID="@carrier.GuID" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#@idForCarrier" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="">
                                                                @carrier.DisplayName
                                                            </a>
                                                        </div>
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>

                                                <div id="@idForCarrier" data-parent="#carrierResults" class="collapse">
                                                    <div class="col-md-12">
                                                        <div class="col-md-1"></div>
                                                        <div class="col-md-11">
                                                            <div class="mb-0" id="@idforcsmain">
                                                                <div>
                                                                    <a class="LinkedObjects" id='' data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#idforcarrierservice" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseOne">
                                                                        Services
                                                                    </a>
                                                                </div>
                                                                <div class="col-md-12">
                                                                    <div class="col-md-1"></div>
                                                                    <div class="col-md-11">
                                                                        <div id="idforcarrierservice" data-parent="#@idforcsmain">
                                                                            @{ foreach (var service in carrier.Services)
                                                                                {
                                                                                    <div class="sidebar-item" data-parent="@idForCarrier">
                                                                                        <a class="LinkedObjects" asp-controller="RegisteredCarriersAndDocuments" asp-action="GetService" asp-route-Symbol="@service.Symbol" asp-route-CarrierSymbol="@carrier.Symbol">
                                                                                            @service.DisplayName
                                                                                        </a>
                                                                                    </div>
                                                                                }
                                                                            }
                                                                        </div>
                                                                    </div>
                                                                </div>
                                                            </div>

                                                            <div id="@idForCarrier" data-parent="#carrierResults" class="collapse">
                                                                <div class="">
                                                                    <div class="mb-0" id="@idforcdmain">
                                                                        <div>
                                                                            <a class="LinkedObjects" id='' data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#idforcarrierdocument" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseOne">
                                                                                Documents
                                                                            </a>
                                                                        </div>
                                                                        <div class="col-md-12">
                                                                            <div class="col-md-1"></div>
                                                                            <div class="col-md-11">
                                                                                <div class="Last-Indent" id="idforcarrierdocument" data-parent="#@idforcdmain">
                                                                                    @{ foreach (var document in carrier.Documents)
                                                                                        {
                                                                                            var idForDocument = @carrier.Symbol + @document.Symbol;
                                                                                            <div class="sidebar-header" id="#@idforcarrierdocument" data-parent="@idForCarrier">
                                                                                                <div>
                                                                                                    <div>
                                                                                                        <a class="LinkedObjects" asp-controller="RegisteredCarriersAndDocuments" asp-action="GetCarrierDocumentDetail" asp-route-CarrierSymbol="@carrier.Symbol" asp-route-DocumentSymbol="@document.Symbol">
                                                                                                            @document.DisplayName
                                                                                                        </a>
                                                                                                    </div>
                                                                                                    <div class="col-md-12 accordion" id="@idforcdoption">

                                                                                                        <div class="col-md-11">

                                                                                                            <a class="LinkedObjects" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#@idforcarrierdocumentoption" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="">
                                                                                                                Output Options
                                                                                                            </a>

                                                                                                        </div>

                                                                                                        <div class="col-md-10" id="@idforcarrierdocumentoption">
                                                                                                            <div class="col-md-12">
                                                                                                                <div class="col-md-2"></div>
                                                                                                                <div class="col-md-10">
                                                                                                                    <div data-parent="@idforcdoption">
                                                                                                                        @{ foreach (var option in document.Options)
                                                                                                                            {
                                                                                                                                <div class="sidebar-item">
                                                                                                                                    <a class="LinkedObjects" asp-controller="RegisteredCarriersAndDocuments" asp-action="GetCarrierDocumentOption" asp-route-option="@JsonConvert.SerializeObject(@option)">
                                                                                                                                        @option.Stock.ToString() , @option.Output.ToString()
                                                                                                                                    </a>
                                                                                                                                </div>
                                                                                                                            }
                                                                                                                        }
                                                                                                                    </div>
                                                                                                                </div>
                                                                                                            </div>
                                                                                                        </div>

                                                                                                    </div>
                                                                                                </div>
                                                                                            </div>
                                                                                        }
                                                                                    }
                                                                                </div>
                                                                            </div>
                                                                        </div>
                                                                    </div>
                                                                </div>
                                                            </div>
                                                        </div>
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                            }
                                        }
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div id="masterdocuments">
                                    <h4 class="mb-0">
                                        <a class="LinkedObjects" id='' data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#ShowDocuments" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseOne">
                                            Registered Documents
                                        </a>
                                    </h4>
                                </div>
                                <div id="DocumentResults" class="col-md-12" data-parent="#masterdocuments">
                                    <div class="col-md-12">
                                        @{
                                            var GenericDocumentCount = 0;
                                            var GenericDocumentOptionCount = 1;
                                            foreach (var document in Model.RegisteredDocs)
                                            {

                                                var idFordocument = @document.Symbol + @GenericDocumentCount;
                                                var idForDocumentOption = @document.Symbol + @GenericDocumentOptionCount;
                                                var idfordocsmain = idForDocumentOption + @count;

                                                <div id="ShowDocuments" class="">
                                                    <div class="parent-Cards" id="carrierParent">
                                                        <div class="parent-Card" id="@document.GuID">
                                                            <a class="LinkedObjects" asp-controller="RegisteredCarriersAndDocuments" asp-action="GetDocument" asp-route-GUID="@document.GuID" data-target="#@idFordocument" data-toggle="collapse" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="">
                                                                @document.DisplayName
                                                            </a>
                                                        </div>
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>

                                                <div id="@idFordocument" data-parent="#DocumentResults" class="collapse">
                                                    <div class="">
                                                        <div class="mb-0" id="@idfordocsmain">
                                                            <div class="col-md-1"></div>
                                                            <div class="col-md-11">
                                                                <a class="LinkedObjects" id='' data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#idfordocumentoptions" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseOne">
                                                                    Output Options
                                                                </a>
                                                            </div>
                                                            <div class="col-md-12" id="idfordocumentoptions" data-parent="#@idfordocsmain">
                                                                <div class="col-md-4"></div>
                                                                <div class="col-md-8">
                                                                    @{ foreach (var option in document.Options)
                                                                        {
                                                                            <div class="sidebar-item" data-parent="#@idFordocument">
                                                                                <a class="LinkedObjects" asp-controller="RegisteredCarriersAndDocuments" asp-action="GetCarrierDocumentOption" asp-route-option="@JsonConvert.SerializeObject(@option)">
                                                                                    @option.Stock.ToString() , @option.Output.ToString()
                                                                                </a>
                                                                            </div>
                                                                        }
                                                                    }
                                                                </div>
                                                            </div>
                                                        </div>
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                            }
                                        }
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
.mb-0 > a {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
}
.mb-0 > a:after {
  content: "\f078"; /* fa-chevron-down */
  font-family: 'FontAwesome';
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
}
.mb-0 > a[aria-expanded="true"]:after {
  content: "\f077"; /* fa-chevron-up */
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div id="accordion">
  <div class="card">
    <div class="card-header" id="heading-1">
      <h5 class="mb-0">
        <a role="button" data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapse-1" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapse-1">
          Item 1
        </a>
      </h5>
    </div>
    <div id="collapse-1" class="collapse show" data-parent="#accordion" aria-labelledby="heading-1">
      <div class="card-body">

        <div id="accordion-1">
          <div class="card">
            <div class="card-header" id="heading-1-1">
              <h5 class="mb-0">
                <a class="collapsed" role="button" data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapse-1-1" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapse-1-1">
                  Item 1 > 1
                </a>
              </h5>
            </div>
            <div id="collapse-1-1" class="collapse" data-parent="#accordion-1" aria-labelledby="heading-1-1">
              <div class="card-body">

                  <div id="accordion-1-1">
                    <div class="card">
                      <div class="card-header" id="heading-1-1-1">
                        <h5 class="mb-0">
                          <a class="collapsed" role="button" data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapse-1-1-1" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapse-1-1-1">
                            Item 1 > 1 > 1
                          </a>
                        </h5>
                      </div>
                      <div id="collapse-1-1-1" class="collapse" data-parent="#accordion-1-1" aria-labelledby="heading-1-1-1">
                        <div class="card-body">
                          Text 1 > 1 > 1
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="card">
                      <div class="card-header" id="heading-1-1-2">
                        <h5 class="mb-0">
                          <a class="collapsed" role="button" data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapse-1-1-2" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapse-1-1-2">
                            Item 1 > 1 > 2
                          </a>
                        </h5>
                      </div>
                      <div id="collapse-1-1-2" class="collapse" data-parent="#accordion-1-1" aria-labelledby="heading-1-1-2">
                        <div class="card-body">
                          Text 1 > 1 > 2
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="card">
                      <div class="card-header" id="heading-1-1-3">
                        <h5 class="mb-0">
                          <a class="collapsed" role="button" data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapse-1-1-3" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapse-1-1-3">
                            Item 1 > 1 > 3
                          </a>
                        </h5>
                      </div>
                      <div id="collapse-1-1-3" class="collapse" data-parent="#accordion-1-1" aria-labelledby="heading-1-1-3">
                        <div class="card-body">
                          Text 1 > 1 > 3
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>

              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="card">
            <div class="card-header" id="heading-1-2">
              <h5 class="mb-0">
                <a class="collapsed" role="button" data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapse-1-2" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapse-1-2">
                  Item 1 > 2
                </a>
              </h5>
            </div>
            <div id="collapse-1-2" class="collapse" data-parent="#accordion-1" aria-labelledby="heading-1-2">
              <div class="card-body">
                Text 1 > 2
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>      
      
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    <div class="card-header" id="heading-2">
      <h5 class="mb-0">
        <a class="collapsed" role="button" data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapse-2" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapse-2">
          Item 2
        </a>
      </h5>
    </div>
    <div id="collapse-2" class="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" aria-labelledby="heading-2">
      <div class="card-body">
        Text 2
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    <div class="card-header" id="heading-3">
      <h5 class="mb-0">
        <a class="collapsed" role="button" data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapse-3" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapse-3">
          Item 3
        </a>
      </h5>
    </div>
    <div id="collapse-3" class="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" aria-labelledby="heading-3">
      <div class="card-body">
        Text 3
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Are you looking for this ? because your code is too clumsy and question is not clear.

Reference from [here](https://codepen.io/glebkema/pen/QQOZRe)

Comment: Yes please, Can the same be incorporated in my code? I am trying to achieve the same but I do not get anything from it

Comment: replace the data in my code if the same you think you required. Then your problem is solved hope so